# Can I have new Console windows (from Win 10) in Windows 8?

Tags: console, windows-10-preview

The new Windows 10 Technical previews has a "fixed" console windows. Is there anyway I can install just that on my Windows 8 without the not-yet-stable Win 10?

Comment: I guess console windows is a feature of Windows 10 right?  Is it available for download for Windows 8?

Comment: That's my question :-)

Comment: @Prasanna Just google for it. First result will give you this info. It seems this is so new it hasn't been ported to older versions yet, and is still in development.

Comment: Why do not to use alternatives available for years? ConEmu for example...

Comment: I use this addon: https://mridgers.github.io/clink/ to get CTRL+V Support